# Dynamic weight for Blocks

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

I want to change the block weight in sidebar for each page request, So the blocks position would be change for each request.

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 8 is providing a hook to alter the region [template_preprocess_region](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_region/8.2.x), it would prepares values to the theme_region.Adding the following codes in THEMENAME.theme file would solve the problems,

```
function themename_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['region'] == 'sidebar_second') {
    $variables['elements'] = shuffle_assoc($variables['elements']);
    $content = '';
    foreach ($variables['elements'] as $key => $value) {
      if (is_array($variables['elements'][$key])) {
        $content .= \Drupal::service ('renderer')->render($value);
      }
    }
    $variables['content'] = array(
      '#markup' => $content,
    );
  }
}

function shuffle_assoc($list) {
  if (!is_array($list)) {
    return $list;
  }

  $keys = array_keys($list);
  shuffle($keys);
  $random = array();
  foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $random[$key] = $list[$key];
  }
  return $random;
}
```

For more details, check [here](http://leopathu.in/content/dynamic-block-weight-drupal-8)

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7, you could use something like [hook_block_list_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_list_alter/7.x) to alter the blocks on the page. Keep in mind that you might also want to use something [like that](https://api.drupal.org/comment/59333#comment-59333) to make this work.

Alternatively, something for Drupal 8 too, you can create a (block) view that contains whatever you're displaying in these blocks in a single block and then just sort them randonly.